# Database message system between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, message

I'm building a database model in mysql workbench.
I have this situation, I have a table students a table teachers and a table messages.
One as a student should be able to send messages to other students and to teachers, and same for teachers, should be able to send messages to students and other teachers, I just wanted to know if the way I encouraged it, is okay, or if there's a better solution?

I tried thinking about n:m relations between all three tables, but didn't get a nice result.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `messages` entity should contain information about messages, not roles of `from` or `to`. A much more simple structure would be:

```
roles
-----
role_id
description

users
------
user_id
role_id (references roles.role_id)

messages
------
message_id
from_id (references users.user_id)
to_id (references users.user_id)
datetime
message
```

Comment: so you think its better to have teachers and students in a single table as "users" and define their role there? the thing is that teachers will also have an excersises table which is just for teachers, and student will have like, student_did_excersise, from that excersises table.

Comment: It's not better, that's just how normalization works.

Comment: okay, thanks a lot, if i found in trouble in that second part i`ll ask again ehhe, thanks

Comment: do you have by any chance, a doc or a link, to read about database normalization?

Comment: @SebastianUrielMurawczik Certainly. [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) or [Normalizacja bazy danych](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizacja_bazy_danych)